# Check what type a list class is of in java

Tags: java, class, generics

Given that I have a

```
Class<?> clazz
```

I want to verify if `clazz` is a list of my specific object

So I started with

```
if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {

}
```

but up till here I only verified that it is `List<?>`. How can I verify for example it is a `List<String>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. Due to the nature of generics, at runtime the type information is erased. If you have an empty `List`, you can't tell anything for sure. If it's non-empty, you can check the first element and see if it's a `String`. That of course won't tell whether it's a `List<String>`, `List<CharSequence>` or a raw list.

What do you intend to do with the information if you get it? There's bound to be a better approach.